# How do I call FB.ui in a Facebook Canvas app?

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, sdk, payment

I want to create a site with Facebook login, where simple payments allow users to buy virtual goods.

From what I understand, the Facebook payments system (popups, etc.) only work with Canvas apps or mobile. So, I have set up my app namespace and canvas page url so that app.facebook.com/### includes the page that I want.

To check that a user is logged in and has granted basic permissions to the app, I have:

```
<?php 

 $app_id = "###";

 $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/###";

 $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
 }
 else {
    echo $data["user_id"];
 }

?>
```

in the body of the page. Clearly, some of the user data is available in the $data object.

However, now that I want to have a payment button, I need to use the JS SDK to call `FB.ui(...)`. Even more simply, just to access `FB.me(...)` I need to go through and asynchronously load the JS SDK, do `FB.init(...)` and check for login status just so that I can call the `FB.me` and `FB.ui` functions. Is this correct? I get the impression that the above PHP already has some of this data, so do I really need to reconnect with Javascript to call these functions? When I do this, I just get the `response.id` or other user data to be 'undefined'.

In general, I just want to know - how do I use basic api calls in a Facebook app running in a canvas?

The payments tutorial is all in JS but the app has to be in canvas, which is redirected with PHP.

### EDIT

I should have made it clear; `FB.me(...)` is returning undefined as are other `FB.` functions. The JS is the standard, copied-and-pasted from the tutorial code, async loading the sdk, wrapping `FB.init()` and other functions in `window.fbAsyncInit`. For some reason, being in the canvas seems to prevent the standard JS SDK from working.

Comment: Of course you need to initialize the JS SDK before you can use any of its methods. And what’s your problem with using JS in a PHP generated page?

Comment: Just to confirm, does that mean I still need to check for login and permissions with the JS SDK, even though I am in the canvas, where the user is prompted by the PHP for login and permissions? It's not a problem with that per se - I thought the non-functionality might be coming from that 'repeated' checking.

Comment: Yes you do: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Comment: _“For some reason, being in the canvas seems to prevent the standard JS SDK from working.”_ – no, it does absolutely not. And you don’t have to go through the login flow again with the JS SDK if you have already directed the user there in your server-side script. `FB.getLoginStatus` helps you determine if you have a valid user session (when needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you're using PHP SDK doesn't mean you shouldn't use javascript SDK, as in manner of fact they were build to be used together, creating a better connection through the client side and the server side.

I use javascript SDK to handle the user status(is logged, is app authorized, etc), to handle the dialogs and the interactions the user has with plugins from facebook and their respective responses and to handle the events fired by the actions of the user.

On the server side, I use PHP SDK to query facebook or to retrieve information about the user, I also always validate the user on the server side.